# mysql:Displaying of two rows in a single row

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.EffectiveDate),'%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`,
       CONCAT(a.FirstNm,' ',IFNULL(a.MiidleNM,' '),' ',IFNULL(a.LastNM,' ')) AS `EmployeeName`, 
       `b`.`BranchName` AS `Branch`
  FROM `tbl_employeemaster` AS `a` 
  JOIN `tbl_branch` AS `b` ON a.BrnNm = b.idBranch     
UNION     
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(c.EffectiveDate),'%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`,
       CONCAT(c.FirstNm,' ',IFNULL(c.MiidleNM,' '),' ',IFNULL(c.LastNM,' ')) AS `EmployeeName `, 
       `d`.`BranchName` AS `Branch`     
  FROM `tbl_employeehistory` AS `c`    
  JOIN `tbl_branch` AS `d` ON c.BrnNm = d.idBranch
```

...is the output:

```
Date        EmployeeName   Branch
-------------------------------------
15-01-2011  ABCD           Bangalore
10-10-2010  ABCD           Magalore
```

...but i want the output as shown below

```
EmployeeName    Branch      Date        previous Branch     Date
ABCD        Bangalore       15-01-2011  Mangalore       10-10-2010
```

Comment: Please post the table schema.

Comment: You should really consider using longer aliases for your tables.  Single letter table aliases are easier to type, but when you come back to this in six months and try to read your query, you'll with you had more descriptive names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT a.EmployeeName,
           a.Branch,
           a.Date, b.branch previousBranch,
                   b.Date previousDate
    FROM
      ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.EffectiveDate),'%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`,
               CONCAT(a.FirstNm,' ',IFNULL(a.MiidleNM,' '),' ',IFNULL(a.LastNM,' ')) AS `EmployeeName`,
               `b`.`BranchName` AS `Branch`
       FROM `tbl_employeemaster` AS `a`
       INNER JOIN `tbl_branch` AS `b` ON a.BrnNm = b.idBranch) a
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(c.EffectiveDate),'%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date`,
              CONCAT(c.FirstNm,' ',IFNULL(c.MiidleNM,' '),' ',IFNULL(c.LastNM,' ')) AS `EmployeeName `,
              `d`.`BranchName` AS `Branch`
       FROM `tbl_employeehistory` AS `c`
       INNER JOIN `tbl_branch` AS `d` ON c.BrnNm = d.idBranch) b
   ON a.EmployeeName = b.EmployeeName
```

Comment: a `LEFT JOIN` might be more appropriate. if the employee has no prev jobs